# how to get initial phase of a signal?

Tags: matlab, signals, signal-processing

I have an acoustic signal with frequency F1 (obtained by FFT) received by a microphone. The signal I get from the microphone is like such a sequence: [N1,N2,N3,...,S1,S2....], where N is the samples(maybe white noise) before the target signal comes, S1 is the first sample of the target signal. As I don't know the starting point of the signal, which sample in the sequence is S1 is unknown.
My question is: in such a situation, how to get the initial phase of S1 in matlab?
It seems that fft cannot be used to cope with this problem when the starting point is unknown.

Comment: You could use a spectrogram to determine when the signal starts, truncate the sequence so it contains only signal, then use the initial phase relative to the starting time of the truncated sequence (found using FFT) and the signal frequency to solve for the phase relative to the starting time of the original sequence.

Comment: Could you provide an example ? Preferably, an audio file format (e.g. .wav file) so experimenting on it will be reproducible.

Comment: This is two of my signals. the sampling frequency is 44100Hz.https://www.dropbox.com/sh/pnjrc4eyv1w2at7/AADvS6yJ85EEWTNzzd8ivNQza?dl=0